# mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given Error

Tags: php, mysqli

I have added the following line:

```
$userquery = mysqli_real_escape_string ($db, $userquery);
```

To the code that worked before I added it, and now I get the following 2 errors:

```
 mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
```

**AND**

```
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given
```

**Code**

```
  $userquery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE forename = '$forename'") or die ("error getting information from database.");
    $userquery = mysqli_real_escape_string ($db, $userquery);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($userquery) == null ){
        die ("No staff directory found");
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting these errors and what I can do to fix them?

I understand the first error is because of $userquery being used twice, but if i dont use it twice how can I use the mysqli_real_escape_string extension?

*I have tried changing the variable names of the first $userquery which gets rid of the errors but then the new error occurs:*

```
mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
```

Comment: You are overriding `$userquery` which contains the results of your query. You'll need to move the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` above the `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: I have also tried that but then I have the error: Undefined variable: userquery

Comment: It might be useful to read up on the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

You need to put your query string through that function first and then put that clean string into the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $forename= mysqli_real_escape_string ($forename);
     $userquery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE forename = '$forename'"); 
        $result= mysqli_fetch_object ($userquery);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == null ){
            die ("No staff directory found");
        }
```

first take various name of variable
you cant take $userquery both time and assigne different value to it so take diffvalue i take `$result`

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string needs 2 parameters

Comment: Surely you need to escape the string _before_ you put it into the query otherwise there is no point in using the function. Plus `mysqli_real_escape_string()` expects the second parameter to be a string. In this example you are passing it the result of `mysqli_query` which is either a boolean or a mysqli_result object.

Answer (score 0):

You are using mysqli_real_escape_string to all query result, and is intended to be used with a string. Using your example you need to:

```
$forename_escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string ($db, forename);
$userquery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE forename = '$forename_escaped'") or die ("error getting information from database.");
if (mysqli_num_rows($userquery) == null ){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This example you have shared has worked to get rid of the errors. Dont you think mysqli_real_escape_string should be added there for prevention of user input such as " 'OR name like %g%

Comment: yes in that referred situation should be added, but the case you presented is a SELECT statement. Tu use to escape user inputs, you should use like this:
mysqli_query($db, 'INSERT INTO staff set forename = " ' . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $forename) . ' " );

Comment: An SQL injection attack can still be performed in a SELECT statement though, just because it isnt injecting anything into the database, it can still draw information that could be private.

Comment: your are right. i've edited the answer, to match the requirements. hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your help and input, seems like its working as it should now

Answer (score 0):

```
$forename = mysqli_real_escape_string ($db, $forename);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE forename = '$forename'";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or trigger_error ($db->error);
if (!mysqli_num_rows($res)){
    die ("No staff directory found");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $userquery = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE forename = '$forename'") or die ("error getting information from database.");
    $userquery = mysqli_real_escape_string ($userquery);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($userquery) == 0){
        die ("No staff directory found");
    }
```

Look 
First,
 
mysqli_real_escape_string() just a parameter,and it is the result value from mysqli_query.
secord,
mysqli_num_rows return a integer value,so you cant use NULL.

Hope to give you help